# On the distribution and the moments of $\max\{1/\sqrt{U_1},...,1/\sqrt{U_n}\}$, where $(U_k)$ is i.i.d. uniform on $(0,1)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, expectation

Let $U_1,U_2,...$ denote an i.i.d. sequence of random variables with the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$. For every integer $n\geq1$, we set $M_n = \max\{1/\sqrt{U_1},...,1/\sqrt{U_n}\}$.

a) Compute the distribution function of $M_n:$

$F_n(x)=\mathbb{P}(M_n\leq x),\qquad x\geq 0.$

Let $p>0$. Specify the values of $p$ for which $\mathbb{E}(M_n^p)<\infty$.

I was able to compute the distribution function, which is

$F_n(x) = (1-\frac{1}{x^2})^n$ for $x\geq1$ and zero otherwise.

which is correct regarding the solution. However, I am having trouble understanding the solution of the second part.

The solution says: 
$\mathbb{E}(M_n^p)\stackrel{\text{1}}{=}\int_0^\infty x^p dF_n(x) = \int_1^\infty x^pn(1-x^{-2})^{n-1}2x^{-3}dx = 2\int_1^\infty x^{p-3}n(1-x^{-2})^{n-1}dx$ and this integral converges if and only if $p-3<-1$ i.e. $p<2$

I cannot see how this is consistent with the definition of the expected value.
In my opinion 1) should be $\mathbb{E}(M_n^p)=\int_0^\infty M_n^p dF_n(x)$ I know that does not make much sense, but can somebody explain the equality 1?

The second thing I do not understand is why this integral converges. How do you see that the value of $\mathbb{E}(M_n^p)$ is finite?? Obviously there is not a chance to compute it.

Comment: "In my opinion 1) should be $\mathbb{E}(M_n^p)=\int_0^\infty M_n^p dF_n(x)$" Why do you think so? "I know that does not make much sense" Indeed. To begin with, did you note that the RHS $\int_0^\infty M_n^p dF_n(x)$ is $M_n^p\int_0^\infty dF_n(x)=M_n^p$?

Comment: Honestly, no. I did not. I thought $dF_n(x) = \frac{d}{dx} ((1-x^{-2})^n)$ and therefore $M_n^p = x^p$.

Comment: You seem to be confusing the random variable $M_n^p$ with a real number $x^p$ where $x$ denotes the argument in an integral. This is a mistake regarding *the nature of the mathematical objects* you are manipulating. // How do you compute $E(u(X))$ for some function $u$ and random variable $X$, already?

Comment: Well if $u:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a measurable function the definition in my script says $\mathbb{E}(u(x))=\int_{\mathbb{R}}u(x)P_X(dx)$ and since $X$ is uniform on $[0,1]$ $P_X(dx) = \mathbb{1}_{\{x\in[0,1]\}}(x)dx$

Comment: (Nobody said that $X$ must be uniform.) So, using $E(u(X))=\int u(x)P_X(dx)$ for $X=M_n$ and $u:x\mapsto x^p$, one gets...

Comment: In this case, replace $u(x)$ with $x^p$ and $P_X(dx) = P_{M_n}(dx)$ one gets $\int_{\mathbb{R}}x^pP_{M_n}(dx)$ and $P_{M_n}(dx)$ is the derivative of the distribution function $F_n(x)=\mathbb{P}(M_n\leq x)$. Then $\int_{\mathbb{R}}x^pn(1+x^{-2})^{n-1}2x^{-3}\mathbb{1}_{\{x\geq 1\}}dx$. Like this?

Comment: Yep, just the definitions.

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much! And how do we see that the integral converges for $p<2$?

Comment: We look at the behaviour of the function to be integrated at the limits of the interval of integration.

Comment: So I consider $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}x^{p-3}2n(1-x^{-2})^{n-1}$ and look at for what $p$ this limit exists? Could you maybe tell me the theorem that allows me to do this?

Comment: No you do not ask that the limit exists (which use would that be if the limit is zero?), you ask that the function behaves like a function whom you know yields a convergent or divergent integral.

Comment: Wild guess: $2nx^{p-3}(1-x^{-2})^{n-1}\leq 2nx^{p-3}$ because $(1-x^{-2})^{n-1}$ is always $\leq 1$ then we have  $\int_1^{\infty}2nx^{p-3}dx=\frac{2nx^{p-2}}{p-2}|_1^\infty$ and if $p=1$ we get $\lim_{x\to\infty}-2n1/x +2n = 2n$ and if $p=2$ this is 0. Does that go in the right direction?

Comment: I am not following, you seem to have no clue about the values of the exponent $q$ such that the integral $$\int_1^\infty x^qdx$$ would converge. Is that so?

Comment: I think it converges if $q<-1$.

Comment: Thus? $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: Thus $p-3<-1$ iff. $p<2$. But what about all the other terms. Especially what about $(1-x^{-2})^{n-1}$ why is that (apparently) insgnificant?

Comment: *Tell us*... Come on, do your job!

Comment: because, since $x\geq 1$; $(1-x^{-2})^{n-1}\leq 1$. I guess.